# Delete all values except the column name row Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
long  short  suggested_long  suggested_short
-2.11  5.11   #N/A           
-4.11  3.66   #REF!           #N/A
93.44  7.55   0               0
1256.4 966.5  563.5           #REF!
```

I want to clear all the values in suggested_long and suggested_short but need to keep the column name rows as I need to insert data after cleaning all the values. Then the result should be:

```
long  short  suggested_long  suggested_short
-2.11  5.11             
-4.11  3.66             
93.44  7.55                 
1256.4 966.5
```

I know some silly ways like delete the two columns and then add the two columns back; but this is not I want.
I assume others may have the same problem, so I post it here, many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have an empty column in pandas. The least you can have is null values.
If you want to fill null values (or any value) you may use the below code:

```
df.suggested_long = np.NaN
df.suggested_short = np.NaN
```

Comment: `nan` is better than `' '`I feel unless one is sure they want string values

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hacky but you could set the values of both columns to be some empty place holder such as `''` or `None`, for example:

```
df[["suggested_long", "suggested_short"]] = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you.

```
df['ColumnName'] = df['ColumnName'].apply(lambda x: ' ' if x else ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just assign a value to the column:

```
df['suggested_long'] = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
data.suggested_long = ""
data.suggested_short = ""
print(data)
```